# MVVMCross Messenger - Subscribing to messages in static class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am just looking into implementing an MVVMCross Messenger solution that will enable me to upload information to Google Analytics  when published from either the iOS application or the PCL.

The problem I have the is that the subscription delgates are not fired after I publish. Can you subscribe to MVVMCross Messenger subscriptions from a static class?

Subscriptions in static class

```
public static class GoogleAnalyticsWrapper //: IDisposable
{
    private const string TrackingId = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    private static readonly IMvxMessenger messenger;
    private static readonly MvxSubscriptionToken screenNameToken;
    private static  readonly MvxSubscriptionToken eventToken;
    private static  readonly MvxSubscriptionToken exceptionToken;
    private static  readonly MvxSubscriptionToken performanceToken;
    private static  readonly MvxSubscriptionToken publishToken;
    private static  bool disposed = false;
    private static  SafeHandle handle;

    static GoogleAnalyticsWrapper()
    {
        Gai.SharedInstance.DispatchInterval = 60;
        Gai.SharedInstance.TrackUncaughtExceptions = true;

        Gai.SharedInstance.GetTracker(TrackingId); 

        messenger = new MvxMessengerHub();// Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
        screenNameToken = messenger.Subscribe<GaScreenNameMessage>((m) => SetScreenName(m));

        int count = messenger.CountSubscriptionsFor<GaScreenNameMessage>();

        eventToken = messenger.Subscribe<GaEventMessage>(CreateEvent);
        exceptionToken = messenger.Subscribe<GaExceptionMessage>(CreateException);
        performanceToken = messenger.Subscribe<GaPerformanceTimingMessage>(CreatePerformanceMetric);
        publishToken = messenger.Subscribe<GaPublishMessage>(PublishAll);
    }

    public static string Dummy { get; set; }

    public static void SetScreenName(GaScreenNameMessage message) 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        Gai.SharedInstance.DefaultTracker.Set(GaiConstants.ScreenName, message.ScreenName);
        Gai.SharedInstance.DefaultTracker.Send(DictionaryBuilder.CreateScreenView().Build());
    }

    public static  void CreateEvent(GaEventMessage message) 
        => Gai.SharedInstance.DefaultTracker.Send(DictionaryBuilder.CreateEvent(message.Category, message.Action, message.Label, message.Number).Build());

    private static  void CreateException(GaExceptionMessage message) 
        => Gai.SharedInstance.DefaultTracker.Send(DictionaryBuilder.CreateException(message.ExceptionMessage, message.IsFatal).Build());

    private static  void CreatePerformanceMetric(GaPerformanceTimingMessage message)
        => Gai.SharedInstance.DefaultTracker.Send(DictionaryBuilder.CreateTiming(message.Category, message.Milliseconds, message.Name, message.Label).Build());

    private static  void PublishAll(GaPublishMessage message) 
        => Gai.SharedInstance.Dispatch();

    public static  void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Dispose managed resources.
                if (handle != null)
                {
                    handle.Dispose();
                }
            }

            // Dispose unmanaged managed resources.
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Publication

```
messengerService.Publish<GaEventMessage>(new GaEventMessage(this, "Event", "Publish Event", "Publish Event From First View Model", 123));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are creating a new `MvxMessengerHub` in your static class, but (**I guess**) inject `IMvxMessenger` in your consuming classes, which is created by MvvMCross during the initialization lifecycle and so a different instance.

The easy solution would be to initialize it in your **App.cs** like

```
public class App : Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        // ...

        var m = Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
        GoogleAnalyticsWrapper.Initialize(m); 
        // ...
    }
}
```

With a wrapper like this

```
public static class GoogleAnalyticsWrapper
{
    static void Initialize(IMvxMessenger messenger)
    {
        Gai.SharedInstance.DispatchInterval = 60;
        Gai.SharedInstance.TrackUncaughtExceptions = true;
        Gai.SharedInstance.GetTracker(TrackingId); 

        screenNameToken = messenger.Subscribe<GaScreenNameMessage>((m) => SetScreenName(m));

        int count = messenger.CountSubscriptionsFor<GaScreenNameMessage>();

        eventToken = messenger.Subscribe<GaEventMessage>(CreateEvent);
        exceptionToken = messenger.Subscribe<GaExceptionMessage>(CreateException);
        performanceToken = messenger.Subscribe<GaPerformanceTimingMessage>(CreatePerformanceMetric);
        publishToken = messenger.Subscribe<GaPublishMessage>(PublishAll);
    }

    // ...
}
```

### **Advanced Hint**

But as far as I see, you don't even need messaging for this case, because it's one to one "communication". I think it would be nice, if you move the functionality of your GoogleAnalyticsWrapper into a well defined Service like:

```
interface ITrackingService
{  
    void SetScreenName(GaScreenNameMessage message);
    void CreateEvent(GaEventMessage message);
    void CreateException(GaExceptionMessage message);
    void CreatePerformanceMetric(GaPerformanceTimingMessage message);
    void PublishAll(GaPublishMessage message);
}

public class GoogleAnalyticsTrackingService : ITrackingService
{
    private const string TrackingId = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    public GoogleAnalyticsTrackingService()
    {
        Gai.SharedInstance.DispatchInterval = 60;
        Gai.SharedInstance.TrackUncaughtExceptions = true;

        Gai.SharedInstance.GetTracker(TrackingId);
    }

    public void SetScreenName(GaScreenNameMessage message) 
    {
        Gai.SharedInstance.DefaultTracker.Set(GaiConstants.ScreenName, message.ScreenName);
        Gai.SharedInstance.DefaultTracker.Send(DictionaryBuilder.CreateScreenView().Build());
    }

    public void CreateEvent(GaEventMessage message) 
    {
        Gai.SharedInstance.DefaultTracker.Send(DictionaryBuilder.CreateEvent(message.Category, message.Action, message.Label, message.Number).Build());
    }   

    private void CreateException(GaExceptionMessage message) 
    {
        Gai.SharedInstance.DefaultTracker.Send(DictionaryBuilder.CreateException(message.ExceptionMessage, message.IsFatal).Build());
    }

    private void CreatePerformanceMetric(GaPerformanceTimingMessage message)
    {
        Gai.SharedInstance.DefaultTracker.Send(DictionaryBuilder.CreateTiming(message.Category, message.Milliseconds, message.Name, message.Label).Build());
    }

    private void PublishAll(GaPublishMessage message) 
    {
        Gai.SharedInstance.Dispatch();
    }
}
```

That has to be registered in your App

```
Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<ITrackingService, GoogleAnalyticsTrackingService>();
```

And can be consumed with constructor injection or manual resolves

```
class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel 
{
    public MyViewModel(ITrackingService tracking)
    {
         tracking.CreateEvent(new GaEventMessage(this, "Event", "Publish Event", "Publish Event From First View Model", 123));
    }
}

// or
class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel 
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
         var tracking = Mvx.Resolve<ITrackingService>();
         tracking.CreateEvent(new GaEventMessage(this, "Event", "Publish Event", "Publish Event From First View Model", 123));
    }
}
```

There is still one Problem: The interface has still a dependency to google analytics. But the dependency can be easily removed by using multiple parameters instead of a parameter object.

```
interface ITrackingService
{
    void CreateEvent(string eventName, string title, string message, params object[] additionalParams);
    // ...
} 

// call:
tracking.CreateEvent("Event", "Publish Event", "Publish Event From First View Model", 123);
```

With this, you are able to unit test it and exchange the tracking service with litte effort, if your stakeholders decide to switch to adobe omniture or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for this, it wasn't the perfect fix for the problem but got me out of the rabbit hole I was stuck in.